# Array of Arithmetic Operators

Tags: python, arrays, perl

I am working on a math problem where I need to test different combinations of numbers and mathematical operations (+,-,*,/). Can I create an array of arithmetic operations in Perl or Python so that I can cycle through these combinations?

Example:
(underscore indicates some operation, letters are variables for integers)

A_B_C_D

could be

A+B+C+D
or
A*B+C-D
or
A-B/C+D
etc...

I need to test be able to test integral values in all of these combinations without manually creating each expression (I believe there are 256 possible combinations for the above example).

Thanks

Comment: Is "A + A + A + A" legit?  or is it always only one of the numbers?

Comment: That is not legit - each number can only be used once.

Answer (score 2):

In Python,

```
import operator

ops = [operator.add, operator.sub, operator.mul, operator.div]
```

Your problem doesn't seem to consider order of operations, ie you will not get `(A + B) / (C - D)`, or `(B / A + D) / C`. Is this important?

**Edit:**

```
from itertools import product
from operator import add, sub, mul, div

def make_function(x, y, z):
    """
    Return a function that implements `(((A x B) y C) z D)`
      where x,y,z are two-argument operators
    """
    def fn(a, b, c, d):
        return z(y(x(a, b), c), d)
    return fn

# list: all unique operations
ops     = [add, sub, mul, div]

# generator: all combinations of three operators
combos  = product(ops, repeat=3)

# list: all functions implementing a three-operator combination
all_fns = [make_function(*trio) for trio in combos]
```

Comment: I have other expressions with brackets that I would manually write into the program. I think there are 11 possible placements of brackets.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Could you explain your answer a bit more so I know how to use it? Thanks

Comment: I really appreciate your help, but I am a beginner, so I don't understand most of what you sent me (even after thinking about it and googling the stuff I didn't know). If you have time, would you be able to explain how I would do this simply? I planned to do a nestled for loop where I would have ops[i] = x, ops [j] = y, ops[k] = z, and then have a list of combinations that would be tested. Ex: AxByCzD, (AxB)yCzD, (AxB)y(CzD)

Answer (score 2):

```
use Algorithm::Loops qw( NextPermute );

my %OPS = (
   '+' => sub { $_[0] + $_[1] },
   '-' => sub { $_[0] - $_[1] },
   '*' => sub { $_[0] * $_[1] },
   '/' => sub { $_[0] / $_[1] },
);

my @OPS = keys(@OPS);

sub evaluate {
   my ($vals, $ops) = @_;

   $vals = [ @$vals ];

   my $acc = shift(@$vals);{
   for my $op (@$ops) {
      $acc = $OPS{$op}->($acc, shift(@$vals));
   }

   return $acc;
}

my @vals = ...;

my @indexes = 0..$#ops;
do {
   my @ops = map $OPS[$_], @indexes;
   my $rv = evaluate(\@vals, \@ops);
   ...
} while (NextPermute(@indexes));
```